# How to check out a shared document using Python 3

Tags: python, excel, sharepoint

I wrote a program that lets end users add/edit data from an Excel spreadsheet. This spreadsheet is a company wide shared document, and therefore it requires users to check out the document before making any changes to it. Is there a way to programmatically check out the document using Python or any other ways that would integrate with Python well?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can have a single program for everyone that has some boolean check if somebody is currently accessing that file or not.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question.. To make any changes I would need to check out the document. My problem right now is that whenever I make a change and save with my program, it doesn't actually save because I never checked out the document.

Comment: What is this checkout ? Is it sharepoint specific ?

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/39420/remotely-programmatically-check-document-in-and-out

Comment: It is a sharepoint document. The thread talks about using Powershell (Sharepoint management consol). I'm not really sure how to use/download Sharepoint management consol and how that could integrate with my Python code. So if you could provide some insight that would be great. Thanks!